# In the Davisson-Germer experiment, where is the coherence?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Experiment of diffraction using light, we use laser beam because we need coherence. In Davisson-Germer experiment, there is no coherence but why the electrons diffract in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the diffraction of light no coherent laser light is necessary, as is known from the diffraction of ordinary light in diffraction gratings. The observed interference effects occur in single photons with themselves. The same happens in the diffraction of x-rays in crystal lattices. The diffraction of electrons in crystals, as demonstrated in the Davisson-Germer experiment, is due to the de Broglie wave properties of electrons. It is completely analogous to the diffraction of x-rays in crystal lattices. No coherence of different electron waves is needed. The diffraction effects can be considered to be due to the interference of the de Broglie wave of single electrons with themselves.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. You need the coherence length to be big enough compared to the spacing of the grating.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I didn't know that single particle causes diffraction effect. It's amazing that particle diffracts by its own wave.

Comment: @Job - Single particles experience diffraction effects, as exemplified, e.g., in the diffraction of single photons or electrons in double slit experiments.

Comment: @BenCrowell - You are, of course, right that for the **observation** of interference effects in diffraction experiments the coherence length of light is important. But this is essentially a practical property of the light source. Its monochromaticity and phase constancy is important for the observation of a stationary interference pattern as a superposition of the effects of many particles. The same holds for the preparation electrons beams in a pure quantum mechanical state. For single particles in pure states, you will always have diffraction/interference of the particle wave with itself.

Comment: *For single particles in pure states, you will always have diffraction/interference of the particle wave with itself.* True but not relevant to this question.

Comment: @Job - Here you find a description of the single particle double-slit experiment with photons and also a reference to the same experiment with electrons: http://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/light/youngs-experiment-single-photons.html

Answer (score 0):

> In Davisson-Germer experiment, there is no coherence

I don't think it's meaningful to talk about coherence as a yes/no thing. A wave has a coherence length, which is some number. Apparently the coherence length of their electron  beam was big enough compared to the atomic lattice spacing of the nickel crystal.

You raise an interesting question, though, which is what determines the coherence length of a cathode ray tube.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm not a native English speaker, that I can't understand your writing perfectly. But I can guess that you mean that 'to observe diffraction, length coherence is necessary'.

Comment: @Job - You are right. In my opinion, the coherence length is a measure of a  light/particle source for the practical observation of interference effects in diffraction experiments as a superposition of the effects of many particles. Single particle waves  in pure QM states should always interfere with themselves. That's the hallmark of the wave property of particles.